# React - Deleting rest of the array instead of just one item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's the link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-heisenberg-9cxb9

I have this method: `deleteItem`

This code:

```
  return {
    monsters: prevState.monsters
      .slice(0, deleteItemPosition)
      .concat(
        prevState.monsters.slice(
          deleteItemPosition + 1,
          prevState.monsters.length
        )
      )
  };
```

This is the code I use to remove an item from array on position deleteItemPosition, because I can't use `monsters.splice(deleteItemPosition, 1)` because of immutability.

So why does my monsters array get cut off from deleteItemPosition to the end?
Try it yourself, entering some number 0-5 into "index to delete"

If I update line

```
let deleteItemPosition = this.state.deleteItemPosition;
```

and I hardcode it to, let say

```
let deleteItemPosition = 3;
```

Then I notice the item on position 3 gets removed, as I wanted.

Comment: Removing an item without mutating should be a little simple with ES6, use delete prevState.monsters[deleteItemPosition];      return {...prevState};, that's all that is needed in the setState callback

Comment: Yes it works, thanks. Is this the best practice though?

Comment: Why not, You're not mutating the state and also providing a new copy in return, It has always worked fine for me

Comment: I jumped the gun.. It doesn't work. Once you delete item on position 2, you can't delete item on position 2 again, the array doesn't get refreshed.

Comment: the only reason could be using the array index as keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `deleteItem` function could be simplified like this, also makes sure that no state updates are skipped:

```
deleteItem = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { monsters: prevState.monsters.filter((_, i) => i !== +prevState.deleteItemPosition)};
    })
};
```

The functional update is recommended as your new state(new monsters array) depends on the previous state.

**Update:**

You can use destructuring to avoid using `prevState` all the time. And you need to convert the `deleteItemPosition` to a number because the input's value is a string.

```
deleteItem = () => {
    this.setState(({monsters, deleteItemPosition}) => {
      return { monsters: monsters.filter((_, i) => i !== +deleteItemPosition)};
    })
  };
```

Comment: Thank you, it works well, and it updates the original array and its indexes, just as it should. Is this the best coding practice for removing an item from an array in React?

Comment: @Dalibor Yes, the absolute best possible. I'll argue with anyone who says otherwise :)

Comment: Thanks. I know it's harder to write one-liners than "regular" code, but I'll rather give Sajeeb a selected answer because his solution is much more readable.

Comment: How about instead "+prevState.deleteItemPosition"  I use "+deleteItemPosition". And why plus sign? When did deleteItemPosition change from number to string?

Comment: Thanks. What I meant was this, without destructuring (see my updated Codesandbox to see what I mean and to see that it works fine)

        this.setState(prevState => {return {
          monsters: prevState.monsters.filter((_, i) => i !== +deleteItemPosition)
        }}

Answer (score 1):

Just make a shallow copy of the `monsters` array, apply `Array.prototype.splice` method for deleting your item and return the copied `monsters` array.

```
const copyMonsters = [...prevState.monsters];
copyMonsters.splice(deleteItemPosition, 1);

return {
  monsters: copyMonsters
}
```

Put this code inside the `setState` function in your case.

Comment: Thank you, it works well, and it updates the original array and its indexes, just as it should. Is this the best coding practice for removing an item from an array in React?